# AllowGuestsSignIn parameter in New-AzureADApplication

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Trying to use New-AzureADApplication with the parameter AllowGuestsSignIn which is of type [Nullable[boolean]]
If I don't set any value, I get:

> Missing an argument for parameter 'AllowGuestsSignIn'. Specify a
>   parameter of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]' and try again.

If I pass $true or $false, I get Bad Request:

> New-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing NewApplication
>   Code: Request_BadRequest Message: One or more property values
>   specified are invalid.

I also tried using the specific type in a variable: [Nullable[boolean]]$MyBool
and using 1/0 using true/false as strings, nothing works

Anyone has any idea how to pass this parameter?
By the way, this works fine https://www.exospheredata.com/2017/01/27/how-to-pass-null-to-a-boolean-parameter-in-powershell/

Comment: Can you share the full command you are trying to run (with details anonymized)?

Comment: I also can't find this parameter in the cmdlet help, which version are you using?

Comment: Please provide the specific command you are using, otherwise we could not test for you.

Comment: I am using version 2.0.2.76 of AzureAD
Example for a command:
$myApp = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName -IdentifierUris $appUri -Homepage $appHomePage -ReplyUrls $appReplyURLs -AllowGuestsSignIn $true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, what you are using is `AzureADPreview` powershell module, it is a preview persion,  I believe the feature of the parameter `-AllowGuestsSignIn` has not been implemented yet.

The command `New-AzureADApplication` calls the [`Azure AD Graph API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog), if you catch the request of the command e.g. `New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName joytest123 -AllowGuestsSignIn $true`, you will find it uses the `allowGuestsSignIn` in the request body.

[image]

But if you look into the [`Application Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#application-entity) of AAD Graph, you will find there is no such property supports the `POST` method(also `PATCH`, the `-AllowGuestsSignIn` also not work for `Set-AzureADApplication`).

Comment: How did you figure this is preview?
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.2.76
"Azure Active Directory V2 General Availability Module."
In any case, it turns out this is not the parameter I was after, so this issue is not relevant for me anymore
Thank you for trying to help

Comment: @MickeyCohen There is no such parameter in the [GA doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0), it just in the [preview doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0-preview), I test it with `AzureADPreview` yesterday, and I test it with `AzureAD 2.0.2.76` just now, I did not expect this parameter, not sure why it also in the `AzureAD` module, because it does not in the GA doc. So I think it may not be implemented or a bug, the usage should be correct.

Comment: It appears you are correct. This parameter is not documented in the GA doc, but it is available in the function and looks like it was not implemented. It turns out that what I really needed is AvailableToOtherTenants which is available and working. Thanks!